# Can I start programming with C?

Tags: c

I want to begin programming i  have no previous programming experience so can is start programming with C ?..Some people told me to start with perl or python .. So can i start learnning it without learnning python or perl first ?..And if so is the "Programming in c" book by steve kochan good to start with ?..http://goo.gl/Jh6bE

Comment: Of course you can

Comment: pay attention not to become addicted

Comment: I think the question you're trying to ask is "*Should* I start programming with C" :)

Comment: Go with either Java or C#.  You will appreciate programming more.  There is no reason to stress yourself out with C then get tired of programming.  Pickup something fun and easy to learn. At later time, if you want to get more of system's background, then go with C.

Comment: These answers may be right or wrong depending upon the context in which future readers wish to apply the information. If you're just looking to get into programming because it's the latest economic craze and cool to talk about with friends, then starting with C# or (gag)Java is probably best. If you're looking to get into programming as a career, C/C++ is where you start. This advice is coming from someone who started out with C# and has spent the last three years in the field banging his head on the wall trying to make sense of concepts learned in C++

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to contradict [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079122#5079122) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079105#5079105) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079156#5079156) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079137#5079137) [given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079453#5079453) [by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079120#5079120) [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079158#5079158) [fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079074/can-i-start-programming-with-c/5079112#5079112): before you go off using OOP stuff or higher level languages, you *have to know* what's going on under the hood of all the fancy garbage-collection-template-multiple-inheritance-whatever-voodoo or you will get into trouble sooner or later.

It is absolutely essential to know that every single memory allocation is expensive and that you have to take care of your memory, for example.

I started programming using C and find it quite easy to learn new languages with my C background. Programming isn't about creating fancy user interfaces by dragging-and-dropping controls from a toolbox: that is just the topping. But before applying topping, you need some cake to put it on.  If you don't know how to bake the cake, you'll never create a fancy one.

C is a simple language where you learn how to code some loops, conditionals and so on. It has – aside from pointers and sick `#defines` – almost no weird language constructs. Once you know how to set up the basic stuff, it'll be easy for you to transfer that knowledge to any other language.

I think, learning C is the first step to become the [Duct Tape Programmer](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/09/23.html). If you're *not* interested in that, then it would be perfect to start programming with [BF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)), [FALSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FALSE) or any other language...

Comment: Not all memory allocation is expensive. Some GC heap allocation is almost as fast as regular stack allocation, and you *don't* have to take care of your memory in terms of freeing it and etc. Templates and garbage collection aren't fancy, they're just different. Your answer shows a large degree of ignorance and I'm severely tempted to downvote it.

Comment: @DeadMG: but *in general*, it is. That's the point. There might be some cases where something is being optimized on higher-level languages, but it's good to keep in mind, that you have to take care of your resources.

Comment: @eckes: In general? There is no in general. Either you work with a GC, or you don't. There's no *general* answer. In fact, given the huge popularity of GCed languages, I doubt that it is expensive for the *majority*.

Comment: @DeadMG: IMHO, sooner or later you'll hit a project, where you have no GC and *have to* take care of your resources. If you never knew that memory has to be allocated and freed and relied on some magic going on (and GC **is** magic), you're stuck. Therfore, I'd recommend to do the hard way first and get some simplifications lateron.

Comment: @eckes: GC is *not* magic, it is a part of a program. There are dozens of programming languages written in C that provide garbage collection- like Lua, for example. Pre-providing a GC in a language is no different to pre-providing `printf` or `setjmp`/`longjmp`. Manual memory management is a waste of time if you don't in advance know explicitly that you're going to need it, learning things like polymorphism is *much* more important.

Comment: @DeadMG: *Polymorphism?* Really? I don't know anything that someone that wants to take his **first steps** in programming would need more!

Comment: @eckes: Polymorphism is more widely used than manual memory management.

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't doubt that this could be the case. Car driving is also quite wide spread but my 8 months daughter will have to learn commando crawling before I put her on the steering wheel of my car. This discussion is pointless...

Comment: @eckes: It's not pointless. You need to have motor function to drive a car. You don't need to manage memory to use polymorphism.

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend starting with C.  C wasn't designed to be a teaching language, and some aspects of it aren't very intuitive.  It introduces a lot of complexity up front, and you'll be spending more time asking why something isn't working the way you want it to than actually getting things done.

As introductory programming languages go, Python is much friendlier and easier to get started in.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do, but I really wouldn't recommend it. Most active software development occurs in vastly, vastly different languages like C++, Java and C#. You'd be learning a language whose heyday is many years past, and whose best practices are decades out of date.

Comment: But he'd be learning stuff about memory management - not too bad to learn that before working with a managed language (which are at least Java and C)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I agree with you. C may be old, but it teaches you *very* important things

Comment: Good luck with memory management. Memory management is possibly one of the biggest problems for novices looking to learn C or C++.

Comment: @John: C. Not C++- we have RAII and smart pointers for that. @ThiefMaster: Why? Memory management is the exact skill you *don't* need to write Java or C#.

Comment: Knowing about it is still a good thing.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Of course it is. But in that time, he could learn something else that will be more useful.

Comment: -1 for this "You'd be learning a language whose heyday is many years past, and whose best practices are decades out of date." 

You seems are locked-in into PC development. Try to look at other options - embedded device programming or GPU development in which C is mainstream. So ...

Comment: @0x69: Which are massively minority markets compared to the other markets. DirectX and OGL both provide their own GPU languages, which are far more common than C. Embedded development isn't all about C either- there are plenty of embedded or mobile devices which run Java, let alone C++ or Objective-C.

Comment: @DeadMG: DirectX HLSL and OGL GLSL languages are subset of C language. So still they are a lot closer to C language than to C++. And yep,- there are object-oriented compilers for embedded devices, but still one can choose random embedded device and there would be 99% probability that this device will have C compiler. This you can't say about C++/Java/Obj-C. So...

Comment: @0x69: They are not subsets. HLSL contains classes and templates, let alone the additional semantics like annotations, semantics themselves. More important than how many embedded devices is how much embedded development goes on for them, where some platforms like iPhone and Android clearly are the mass majority.

Comment: @DeadMG
http://gpwiki.org/index.php/DirectX:Tutorials:HLSL:Introduction
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLSL
tells that HLSL/GLSL are based on C. Of course they are a *bit* extended. Still i see no evidence of OO paradigm in them. About HLSL classes - are you sure ? Maybe it is just C structs ? 
About last claim - in iPhone you can develop using plain C. Also the same holds for Android - you can use C sources by using NDK. So...

Comment: @0x69: Based on and can use are not the same as common or even related.

Comment: Same or not same, but your claim "You'd be learning a language whose heyday is many years past" is exaggerated as I showed already. Also check tiobe C index -
http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html
C is almost TWO times more popular than C++. So make conclusions.

Comment: @0x69: Who are these people and why are their ratings respectable? Even if I accept their numbers, then it says themselves that the rating is based on LoC. Having a lot of LoC in a language does *not* make it a smart idea to learn that language, or indeed that that language's heyday is not long past. Just because you *can* use C or because there are existing codebases in it, does *not* mean that learning it now is a smart idea.

Comment: "Just because you can use C or because there are existing codebases in it, does not mean that learning it now is a smart idea. "

I think vice versa - it is always smart idea to know fundamentals.

Comment: @0x69: The fundamentals of C are not the same as the fundamentals of more common languages. And C is not even remotely twice as popular as C++, Java, and C#- just to name a few. You're not just competing against C++ here, it's *all* of the new generation OOP languages.

Comment: @DeadMG
I think you missed my point. Point is that for embedded systems C is mainstream language (even if it is hard to you to face it). So C has it's own niche and because of that it certainly is not "out of date".
For example just go to 
http://www.indeed.co.uk
and make such search-
"embedded c" - 2,349 jobs + CUDA + OpenCL (200 jobs)
"embedded c++" - 161 jobs
"embedded java" - 10 jobs
So seems for embedded development C is winner.

Answer (score 1):

Entire generations of programmers started with C, no reason you can't either.
Python is an overall easier language to learn however than is C, so you might be able to learn the basic principles more quickly than you would starting with C.

As to the book you mention, I've never read it so can't comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend learning to program in a higher-level intepreted language such as Perl, PHP, Python... if you then want to go lower-level and learn C, you'll have a good basis, and won't have been "thrown in the deep end" so much.  You'll also likely find more junior development positions for those languages, if you're looking to start a career.

Having said that, knowing some C can be helpful to give you an understanding of what's going on "under the hood".

Answer (score 1):

You can start programming with C, although C isn't perhaps the best choice for learning. I personally recommend Python since it was designed in part for novices. Perl is probably a bad choice for novices given its interesting syntax. If you need to get close to the machine, or you're going to programming in micro controller space then you will likely need to learn C, but its probably not a good first choice.

I can't comment on *Programming in C*, but I can recommend *The C Programming Language* if you're a motivated self learner.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* start programming in C.  However, if you've never programmed before, it's almost certainly going to be much easier to learn a higher-level language to begin with. And unless your interest in programming lies in a few narrow areas like operating systems, it's unlikely you'll want to use C in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is of course "Yes", but C may not be the best choice as a first language.

You've to master some fairly advanced concepts before you can do the most basic things.

There are other laguages that are much *friendlier* such as C# and Java. If you know folks with Perl and/or Python experience that will help you, then go with either of those (I'd pick Python as a first language, if I had to choose between Perl, Python or C.

Personally, if I had to help someone get started with Programming I'd get them started with C#, but that's because I work with it everyday, and you can make it as simple or as complex as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Since you have no previous experience, when you learn your first language you are learning two things actually:

1) The syntax of the language, where it wants its commas, curly braces, and stuff like that

2) General programming principles

The reason people tell you to try something simpler, like Python (or PHP would be my suggestion) is that some languages make you type in a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with the problem at hand or what you are trying to learn.  In other words, you spend too much time with some languages learning things that are specific to that language, making it hard to learn general programming.

Anyway, my suggestion would be PHP because they have great tutorials, you can get some programs going that do things, and learn the basics fast.

Also remember: all committed programmers know multiple languages and learn new languages fairly regularly, so the first one you pick will not determine your destiny.  Pick the one that is appealing to you for your own reasons.

...and enjoy!  Welcome to programming!

Comment: Please.. not PHP as the first language. There is no language which has more crappy tutorials/guides in the web and even in printed books. Relying on register\_globals, not properly escaping things, not wrapping database access but using crappy `... or die(...);` constructs, quote-escaping orgies - and much more.

Better go with python - you don't need a webserver to run it (I know php has a CLI version, too, but it's really poor - no interactive mode etc.) and you have a very nice interactive shell (either plain python.exe or the IPython shell).

Comment: i would have upvoted you.. but you suggested php.. @ThiefMaster is right

Comment: I guess religion is a powerful thing.